# Sorting an DevExpress XtraGrid by image column

Tags: c#, devexpress

The task seems to be quite easy.

I want to allow an XtraGrid to be sorted by an image column (Images represent a state)

According to the manual you only need to set the column sort mode to Custom and put a bit of code in CustomColumnSort Eventhandler.

Here it did not work, the eventhandler was never called.

I tried the following explicitly:

```
gridViewLeftGrid.Columns["ImageColumnName"].OptionsColumn.AllowSort = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
gridView.Columns["ImageColumnName"].SortMode = DevExpress.XtraGrid.ColumnSortMode.Custom;
gridView.CustomColumnSort += gridView_CustomColumnSort;
gridView.CustomColumnGroup += grid_CustomColumnGroup; 

void gridView_CustomColumnSort(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnSortEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

But still - a breakpoint in gridView_CustomColumnSort is never reached.

The only impact what i see is that now every time when the grid is loaded or updated an error is thrown from `DevExpress.Data.Storage.DataStorageObjectComparer.CompareRecordsCode` that :

> "At least one Object should implement ICompare"

Can anybody help whats missing?

Answer (score 0):

> Your data source should implement the **IXtraSortable** interface in order
>   to implement the desired sorting

Check [Devex Support Question](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A360)

Comment: Hi, that site seems to be deprecated , see Svetlana from devexpress support on the linked page: "set GridColumn.SortMode property to Custom and handle the GridView.CustomColumnSort event."

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to go through the [ColumnView.CustomColumnSort Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomColumnSorttopic) documentation and see the following lines:

The result of the custom comparison should be set to the CustomColumnSortEventArgs.Result parameter as shown below:

- set Result to -1 if the first row should be positioned above the second row when data is sorted in ascending order. When data is sorted in descending order, the first row will be positioned below the second row.
- set Result to 1 if the first row should be positioned below the second row when data is sorted in ascending order. When data is sorted in descending order, the first row will be positioned above the second row.
- set Result to 0 to indicate that the rows are equal. In this case, the rows will be arranged within the grid according to their indexes in the data source.

**Note:**
The [CustomColumnSortEventArgs.Handled](http://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseCustomColumnSortEventArgstopic.aspx) parameter should be set to `true` if the current comparison operation was `handled`. You can leave this parameter set to false to invoke the default comparison mechanism after your event handler has finished. In this case, the custom comparison operation's result is ignored.

Check the example:

```
protected void grid_CustomColumnSort
(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.CustomColumnSortEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "Country") {
        e.Handled = true;
        string s1 = e.Value1.ToString(), s2 = e.Value2.ToString();
        if (s1.Length > s2.Length)
            e.Result = 1;
        else
            if (s1.Length == s2.Length)
                e.Result = Comparer.Default.Compare(s1, s2);
            else
                e.Result = -1;
    }
}
```

You can implement compare code on event like this also:

```
if (e.Column.FieldName == "Importance")
{
     int n1 = (int)gridControl1.GetCellValue(e.ListSourceRowIndex1, "Rank");
     int n2 = (int)gridControl1.GetCellValue(e.ListSourceRowIndex2, "Rank");

     e.Result = Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(n1, n2); /// comparator here, that set the e.result

     e.Handled = true;
}
```

References:
[How to: Implement Custom Sorting](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3071)
[DXGrid CustomColumnSort not sorting correctly](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B220981.aspx)
[CustomColumnSort not working](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/DB41648.aspx)
[ASPxGridView - How to sort groups](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18508) - it is regarding asp.net grid, but may be helpful

Check the code snippet that raise the custom sort event, by following this KB article - [How to implement custom sorting](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E963.aspx). hope this help:

```
public partial class GridCustomSortTest : Form
{
    public GridCustomSortTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void GridCustomSortTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] months = new string[] { "January", "February", "March", 
            "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
            "October", "November", "December" };

        grid.DataSource = months;
        grid.RefreshDataSource();
        gridView1.Columns[0].SortMode = DevExpress.XtraGrid.ColumnSortMode.Custom;
        gridView1.CustomColumnSort += new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnSortEventHandler(gridView1_CustomColumnSort);


    }

    void gridView1_CustomColumnSort(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnSortEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Result = Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(e.ListSourceRowIndex1,
           e.ListSourceRowIndex2);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the long answer, but... 1. It is as mentioned above an XtraGrid, not an ASPxGrid; 2. The problem is reaching the handler. The program just never reaches a breakpoint in "CustomColumnSort" So the problem is not what the custom handler should return, it is that it is not reached at all. (Like if you use the ASPx page and it would never enter "protected void grid_CustomColumnSort"

Comment: i know that but i just added that reference link for code reference.